# Selecting employees in certain departments using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-sql

I am trying to select the DepartmentName from Employee Table based on where condition. Is any way to simplify the code?

```
List<Department> lstdepartment=(from i in _context.Department 
                                select i).ToList();

    List<Employee>lstEmployee=(from e in _context.Employee
                            where e.EmployeeId=EmployeeId
                            select new EmployeeInfo
                            {
                                EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                                FirstName = e.FirstName,
                                LastName = e.LastName,
                                MiddleName = e.MiddleName,
                                //Need code simplifiaction
                                DepartmentName=lstdepartment.Where(w=>w.DepartmentId==e.DepartmentId)
                                .Select(x=>x.DepartmentName).SingleOrDefault();
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to read up on how to properly set up relationships in your DB and then how to query them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386951.aspx , https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2007/10/02/linq-to-sql-and-one-to-many-relationships/ , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386932.aspx

Comment: To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> lstdepartment
> ```

We don't use Hungarian notation with prefixes like `lst` in C#. It's just `departments`

---

This is notepad coding but you can use a join to get the matching deparment

```
var results = 
    from e in _context.Employee
    join d in _context.Department on e.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId
    where e.EmployeeId = EmployeeId
    select new EmployeeInfo
    {
        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
        FirstName = e.FirstName,
        LastName = e.LastName,
        MiddleName = e.MiddleName,    
        DepartmentName= d.DepartmentName
    }).ToList();
```

although this is not yet exactly what you have because this will yield only exact matches. If you want deparment-name to be null then you need a left join and I think this should work:

```
var results = 
    from e in _context.Employee
    join d in _context.Department on e.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId into ds
    from d in ds.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where e.EmployeeId = EmployeeId
    select new EmployeeInfo
    {
        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
        FirstName = e.FirstName,
        LastName = e.LastName,
        MiddleName = e.MiddleName,    
        DepartmentName= d?.DepartmentName
    }).ToList();
```